# How can i add custom folder when i create flutter project

Tags: flutter

- For example
  **"Create assets folder with 4 base folders automatically when I create the project"**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: create an empty flutter project create all the necessary folders that you require. Push the project on GitHub or  of your choice. Next time you need, clone it.

Answer (score 0):

Do right click on parent project directory and you will get create new directory enter the directory name and your folder or directory created succesfully. You can create directory as required

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using?  You could create a folder somewhere like this

```
temp-folder/assets/
temp-folder/base1/
temp-folder/base2/
temp-folder/base3/
temp-folder/base4/
```

Then just copy paste the above five folders into your project folder.